# Expand all older posts on a Facebook group

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I want to read the posts of a group, except I want to start from the beginning and the group has *a lot* of posts.

I've used Better Facebook and several Greasemonkey scripts to no avail. What else can I do? (Keep in mind I'm expanding the posts on a group.)